# Converting raster (.tif) to ASCII format using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, convert, ascii

I am using ArcMap.

I have 20 .tif raster files, need to convert them to .asc format. However, when I convert, the values in new .asc layers changed totally and it doesn't look like .tif file (all areas are only covered by grey color). In the data layer, I clicked 'Properties', under the 'Source' tab, clicking 'Set Data Source' and selected my original raster .tif layer. It worked and changed values back to the original. But the problem is I cannot export those rasters with changed values as I need them to use in different software.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have the same symbology setting on the asc raster compared to the tif

Comment: It worked. You saved my day, thanks!!!

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the same symbology setting on the asc raster as the tif.

The actual values can be the same but the symbology can make them appear different.